# Django upload form with different models

Tags: html, django, file-upload, django-forms, django-views

I am building my first Django app and I need to have an upload page where I would be able to upload multiple files in different upload forms. I need different forms and, I guess, models since depending on the form the file has to be stored in a respective folder in my media root and go through different further transformations. I also want different users have different levels of access to these uploads.

So far I have something like this (I have quite a bit of additional code inside functions in views.py that send data to data frames or other programs but I am not posting those:

**models.py**

```
class Upload(models.Model):
document = models.FileField(storage=OverwriteStorage(),upload_to=get_file_path)
upload_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =True)


class Upload_variables(models.Model):
    variables = models.FileField(storage=OverwriteStorage(),upload_to=get_file_path_var)
    upload_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from uploader.models import Upload, Upload_variables

class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ('document',)

class UploadFormVar(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload_variables
        fields = ('variables',)
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):  
if request.method=="POST":

    img = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if img.is_valid():
        img.save() 
else:
    img=UploadForm()
files=Upload.objects.all()
return render(request,'home.html',{'form':img})




def variables(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    var = UploadFormVar(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if var.is_valid():
        var.save()

else:
    var = UploadFormVar()
files_st = Upload_variables.objects.all()
return render(request, 'home.html', {'form_b': var})
```

**HTML**

```
        <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %} {{form}} 
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit_form"/>
        </form>

        <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %} {{form_b}} 
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="staging"/>
        </form>
```

So I can see 2 Upload buttons but only one 'choose file'....
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are placing the forms in two separate views. You need to put them in the same view like this:

```
     def home(request):  
            if request.method=="POST":
                  var = UploadFormVar(request.POST, request.FILES)
                  img = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                  if img.is_valid():
                       img.save() 
                  if var.is_valid():
                       var.save()
            else:
                   img = UploadForm()
                   var = UploadFormVar()
            files=Upload.objects.all()
            return render(request,'home.html',{'form': img, 'form_b': var})
```